# df says there is no free space, but there is free space

Tags: disk-space, df

df shows there is no free space, but it also shows there is only 7,9/21G used.

```
Filesystem      Size    Used Avail. Used% Mount path
-> /dev/simfs    21G    7,9G     0  100% /
devtmpfs        2,0G       0  2,0G    0% /dev
tmpfs           2,0G    4,0K  2,0G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2,0G    145M  1,9G    8% /run
tmpfs           5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2,0G       0  2,0G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2,0G     12M  2,0G    1% /tmp
none            2,0G       0  2,0G    0% /run/shm
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. If your question is "why is this happening?" you should ask your container provider that question -- only they will know why their machine isn't giving you the space it promised you.

Comment: You should read this, https://serverfault.com/questions/714219/linux-says-my-space-is-full-with-2-4-50gb-used  This guy has exactly the same problem as you. Best recommendation: change provider, and choose one that does **not** use OpenVZ.

Comment: `df` will print pretty much 1:1 what the kernel reports. So what we have here is either a kernel bug or some sort of quota or whatever. /edit: Or those OpenVZ guys have a very liberal interpretation of what to report as “size”. Oh well.

Comment: Hm, maybe there's a host problem. The aren't any good hosts with fair prices and kvm, I'll stay there until I find something good.^^

Comment: Having experienced a RedHat server, report incorrect usage on a folder, caused by what simply described as a display bug have you confirmed your not running into a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

based on the size you are referring to and without further detail i will assume this is a USB drive.
This is is something fairly common in the internet bought USB drive industry.  Many drives are sold as a larger size than they are capable of holding.  A simple search engine search for "fake flash drive", "fake 2tb flash drive", or "china usb drive size scam" will portray how common this scam is.
Recent Faked Drives have terabyte sizes while older and some new ones as well could be even smaller than 1 GB.

Comment: No, it is not an USB drive: simfs is a directory file system for the virtuozzo container technology, see for instance here, https://anonexp.blogspot.com/2013/01/simfs-openvz-container-filesystem.html